How is this site doing for the beta phase?
Is there a page we can see the stats of this site regarding the beta phase, how time left there is and how is it going?  
I have the impression that it's not getting too many new questions and answers or not doing so fast enough, or at least that's my perception, and as my Chinese level is still low, I can't contribute too much.

You can see the stats in the Proposal's Area51 page, or in the Main Site (click the logo instead of Questions, and look on the right).
I don't think there is a definite end, but probably there's a mention about it on Meta.stackoverflow. I'll check and link it in case...
If you're worried of our visits and questions, you can share the site or share the questions you think other people might like! For example, if in your FB account there are people interested in Chinese or in some things about Chinese, share! :) (Share even if you don't know anyone for that, they can still like it...)

You can also see how our site is doing vs. other sites in the network on this page http://stackexchange.com/sites
From my experience SE sites take a considerable amount of time and effort before they start to build a steady stream of traffic (usually after a year).
So comparatively we are about average for the age of the site compared to similar sites.
Also note that there is no set time limit. The site is assessed after 90 days, but looking at other sites in the network only those sites that are doing considerably poorly or a not a good fit for the network are shut down.
How can you help:

Promote the site to others you think would be interested
Help promote your favourite questions and answers on social networking sites
Help with editing questions and answers to make each question and answer top quality
If you have questions that you already know the answer to but would be beneficial to a lot of others you can still ask it and you can also answer your own questions
Help us reach out to popular Chinese bloggers and communities

